# Laravel API - Pulling large amounts of data (json)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I’ve created an API in my Laravel app to pull all my clients (3000+) details so I can use my AngularJS autocomplete form to search for their name/address/phone number etc.

The API outputs about 1,000Kb of client data (json). If I don’t fetch all the data, I could think that a client doesn’t exist when typing his name in the search box, so I would like to be able to load them all.

Everything work fine, but a 1,000Kb download is a slow. AngularJS handle this well though. And what if I had 10,000 clients?

Where should I look to increase the performance of this fetch:

- Laravel Eloquent query, is there a way to get the data in chucks in this situation?
- Php (gzip) to reduce the size of the pulled data?
- AngularJS to work as soon as the first row is downloaded?

Here is the code I use:

API Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $clients = Client::where('business_id', '=', \Auth::user()->business_id)->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->get();

    return  Response::json([
       'clients' => $this->transformClientCollection($clients)
    ], 200);
}

public function transformClientCollection($clients)
{
    return array_map([$this, 'transformClient'], $clients->toArray());
}

public function transformClient($clients)
{

    return [
        'clientid' => $clients['id'],
        'first_name' => $clients['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $clients['last_name'],
        'address_1' => $clients['address_1'],
        'address_2' => $clients['address_2'],
        'city' => $clients['city'],
        'state' => $clients['state'],
        'postal_code' => $clients['postal_code'],
        'phone_number_1' => $clients['phone_number_1'],
        'phone_number_2' => $clients['phone_number_2'],
        'email' => $clients['email']
    ];
}
```

AngularJS (html file)

```
<div ng-app="instantsearch">
    <div ng-controller="instantSearchCtrl">

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control search" ng-model="searchString" placeholder="Enter your search terms" /> 
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row data-ctrl" ng-repeat="i in items | filter:searchString | limitTo:20 ">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
           @{{ i.first_name }} @{{ i.last_name }} @{{ i.address_1 }} @{{ i.address_2 }} @{{ i.city }} @{{ i.state }} @{{ i.phone_number_1 }} @{{ i.phone_number_2 }} @{{ i.email }}
          </div>             
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

AngularJS (JS file)

```
var app = angular.module('instantsearch',[]);

app.controller('instantSearchCtrl',function($scope,$http,$location){

    var urlapiclients = $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + "/api/clients" ;

    $http.get(urlapiclients).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.items = data.clients;

    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("No data found..");
  });
});


app.filter('searchFor', function(){
    return function(arr, searchString){
        if(!searchString){
            return arr;
        }
        var result = [];
        searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
        angular.forEach(arr, function(item){
            if(item.first_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
            result.push(item);
        }
        });
        return result;
    };
});
```

JSON output

```
   "clients":[
      {
         "clientid":4981,
         "first_name":"Sid",
         "last_name":"Hodkiewicz",
         "address_1":"6659 Hackett Ways",
         "address_2":"",
         "city":"New Estherville",
         "state":"Tennessee",
         "postal_code":"27281-0870",
         "phone_number_1":"00700300842",
         "phone_number_2":"",
         "email":"hNitzsche@Stokes.biz"
      },
      {
         "clientid":4982,
         "first_name":"Braulio",
         "last_name":"Bechtelar",
         "address_1":"7558 Anne Land Suite 876",
         "address_2":"",
         "city":"Rauview",
         "state":"Alabama",
         "postal_code":"01837-9601",
         "phone_number_1":"1-017-001-8215",
         "phone_number_2":"",
         "email":"nBaumbach@gmail.com"
      },
      {
         "clientid":4983,
         "first_name":"Loma",
         "last_name":"Dibbert",
         "address_1":"805 Jones Fields Suite 411",
         "address_2":"",
         "city":"Lake Billychester",
         "state":"New Jersey",
         "postal_code":"69315-4595",
         "phone_number_1":"(691)511-6275x891",
         "phone_number_2":"",
         "email":"dHegmann@Bashirian.net"
      },
      {
         "clientid":4984,
         "first_name":"Verla",
         "last_name":"Schulist",
         "address_1":"89529 Bode Village Suite 344",
         "address_2":"",
         "city":"West Jessy",
         "state":"Virginia",
         "postal_code":"69116",
         "phone_number_1":"(248)211-3643",
         "phone_number_2":"",
         "email":"Friesen.Ruthie@Hand.biz"
      },
      {
         "clientid":4985,
         "first_name":"Jimmie",
         "last_name":"Fadel",
         "address_1":"4355 Marquardt Heights",
         "address_2":"",
         "city":"South Conrad",
         "state":"District of Columbia",
         "postal_code":"55751",
         "phone_number_1":"(414)901-2495",
         "phone_number_2":"",
         "email":"Koepp.Wayne@yahoo.com"
      }
```

Comment: Are you pulling only the information you need?  It would seem if you are just doing an auto complete, all you should need is the name.  It's hard to believe you need a mb of data for 3000 clients.

Comment: I've added examples of my code and output above. I could lose a few Kb if I changed the names `address_1` to `a1` and `phone_number_1` to `p1` for example, but besides that....

Answer (score 1):

It seems a little excessive to return every row in the database only to search it in Javascript.  It may only be 3000 clients at the moment, but I am assuming that this table is intended to grow over time and will only get slower and slower over time.

The best way to implement this would be to only return the clients that match a search query passed from your Javascript application.  For example you could make a request to:

```
http://www.example.com/api/v1/clients?search=foo
```

On the server side, you could do something like:

```
$search = '%'.Input::get('search').'%';

// Just a few of the columns to search
$clients = Clients::where('first_name', 'LIKE', $search)
                   ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', $search)
                   ->orWhere('state', 'LIKE', $search)
                   ->take(10)
                   ->get();
```

Keep in mind that reducing the collection size will reduce the amount being passed from your MySQL server to PHP (which can be slow itself) and over the network to your Angular app.

In response to your comment:

`I've added examples of my code and output above. I could lose a few Kb if I changed the names address_1 to a1 and phone_number_1 to p1 for example, but besides that....`

This would be a minimal bandaid to the problem and I would not necessarily recommend renaming the keys returned.

Comment: Thanks I agree, but I really liked the idea of typing and getting the results I want as I type, without refreshing. Actually, it works fine now, it's just the time to download the entire json that makes it delay a few seconds (2-3secs). But I agree that when my list gets bigger, it's going to get slower. I thought I could use gzip (read that somewhere) to compress the json so it gets smaller

Answer (score 0):

Yeah...probably not a great idea to require a 1 MB download for an autocomplete capability. You've got two main options:

1. Download a complete list of names and ids, ignoring all of those other parameters, and otherwise use your current method
2. Run your autocomplete on an AJAX call

Option 1 is great for smaller lists, and you certainly can design an API call with a much smaller payload than it currently uses.

Once your application scales to a certain size, option 2 becomes the only solution. The drawback is that it's not as quick as loading everything into memory.

Comment: Thanks!. I guess I could retrieve the id and name only so the json output would be a lot smaller. I thought I could use gzip (read that somewhere) to compress the json so it gets smaller